# how to simulate a lamp in libgdx?

Tags: opengl, colors, libgdx

I am using `libgdx` and I was wondering how to simulate a lamp.

What I mean is that I have a background texture and all the colors in it are pretty dark becuase it is suppose to a dark environment. What I want to do is to grab a region of the texture and make all the colors brighter like if it there was a lamp somewhere.

Now, the lamp is supposed to be moving and that will be calculated at run time so it is unpredictable to know where it would be, and the only thing that comes to my mind is to get every pixel from the texture and get the color and just change the rgb values to be higher to have that effect.

The thing is that the lamp is suppose to be moving a lot. It wont stop moving until the game is over and I feel that changing the color of every pixel is kind of a heavy process. Is there another way to it?

By the way, the game is a cartoon so I don't need the lamp too be realistic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you instead layer an alpha blended transparency to darken the visible area except where the lamp is? I plan to use this to achieve a pseudo-lighting effect in a game.

Comment: wow thanks a lot man that's a really good idea never thought of it thanks!! XD